# Get User Roles coresponding to concrete user

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

How to unpack `Task<IList<string>>` to `List` or something else? Im looking a way to get user `Role` (one user have only one `Role` but from this query i get `Task` list and i cant get that role from it. How to deal with that?

My query:

```
var appUser = this.userManager.Users.SingleOrDefault(r => r.UserName == model.UserName);
var appUserRoles = this.userManager.GetRolesAsync(appUser); //Here i get List of task
```

And full method

```
[HttpPost("Login")]
    public async Task<object> Login([FromBody] LoginBindingModel model)
    {
        var result = await this.signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, false, false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var appUser = this.userManager.Users.SingleOrDefault(r => r.UserName == model.UserName);
            var appUserRoles = this.userManager.GetRolesAsync(appUser);

            var bearerToken = await this.GenerateJwtToken(model.UserName, appUser);

            return this.Ok(new AccountViewModel
            {
                //model
            });
        }

        return this.Unauthorized();
    }
```

Or maybe is there way to make `Login` not `async`? Byt in `Identity Core` there is synchrously managers methods.

Comment: Try this  **var appUserRoles = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(appUser).Result.ToList()**  , Gets  the result value of  this Task<TResult>

Comment: If it's async, use await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `await` :

```
 var appUserRoles =await this.userManager.GetRolesAsync(appUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

put an `await` before calling all methods that is decorated with `Task`, to do this you can use something like this :

```
 var userRoles =await this.userManager.GetRolesAsync(appUser);
```

this returns all roles in a `List<T>`, or you can use `Result` , like :

```
var userRoles =this.userManager.GetRolesAsync(appUser).Result;
```

Now you have a list of roles and you can `enumerate` them and choose what you want

```
var role=userRoles.Where(r=>r.name=='admin') ; // example
```